# MongoDB collection fields not showing in same order as they are in model schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am creating some REST api's using mongodb, nodejs and express, and I have user model schema. The way fields are in the user model, after saving the document in mongodb they are not appearing in the same format as they are in the model.

As i am new to mongoDB and nodejs I don't have much idea what to do and the fields are saving in this way, is there anything i can do?

**User Model -**

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: String,
        default: () => (new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()).toString()
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 255,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
    isVerified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        default: 'pet owner',
        enum: ["pet owner", "employee", "admin"]
    },
    status : {
        type: String,
        default: 'active',
        enum: ['active', 'inactive']
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: Number,
        default: null
    },
    countryCode: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    dialCode: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    birthday: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    state: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    city: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    pincode: {
        type: Number,
        default: null
    },
    information: {
        type: String,
        default: null
    },
    resetPasswordToken: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    resetPasswordExpires: {
        type: Date,
        required: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: null
    }
});
```

**After Save -**

```
_id:"5e7c68c08373c5313b104c0a"
isVerified:true
role:"pet owner"
status:"active"
phoneNumber:null
countryCode:null
dialCode:null
birthday:null
address:null
state:null
city:null
pincode:null
information:null
createdAt:2020-03-26 14:03:04.312
updatedAt:null
name:"rahul kundu"
email:"rahul.kundu@massoftind.com"
password:"$2a$10$bHrQA6UXVKmfy4eYQfe1C.dJ6Xj7xUiBWzj90jc9X2npPCfGYEElK"
__v:0
```

Comment: Was the main concern that the fields are not in the same order when logged? Is there a reason you need them to be in the same order?

Comment: no there is no specific reason. Just asked if there is any way to fix it.

Comment: When you create that record, what order were the fields in? According to MongoDB docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-field-order, "MongoDB preserves the order of the document fields following write operations".

Comment: const newUser = new User({ 
        ...req.body, 
        password: hashedPassword,
        createdAt: new Date()
      });

Comment: In this way i am saving when a new user is registering. req.body is name, email, password and side by side updating role, status, isVerified, createdAt and _id updates automatically. Rest of the field's stays null. user will update them during profile update.